# Help Lost Bitcoin phase

Tags: private-key

I was using a Bitcoin wallet called "Bread" then transfer to another wallet called "Bitcoin".  The Bitcoin app was deleted from my IPhone 7.  The password word phase I wrote down was the same as the "Bread" app.  It that possible? Or did I write down my old password thinking I was in my new "Bitcoin" app.  I have tried download the Bitcoin app again but unable to restore the account.
Thank you, John

Answer (score 1):

Though it is possible that both wallets generated the same mnemonic seed phrase (which is used to derive private keys), it is **extremely** unlikely. The chance of it being the same is 1 in 2^256, which is a very small number. This is obviously assuming no bugs in the code generating the key.

Restoring the account is only possible if you still have the mnemonic seed phrase. If you don't, then I'm afraid you won't be able to access the bitcoin until you find the seed.

Note that the mnemonic seed phrase is different than a user-supplied password. A mnemonic seed phrase will derive addresses, whereas a password will encrypt (lock) the wallet. So if you use the seed phrase to recreate the wallet on another device, you will not need the password to access the funds on the second device. That said, in some cases, a user-supplied password may also be used as part of the seed phrase (a '13th word or '25th word'). So you'll need to determine the nature of your password in order to recreate your wallet.

Answer (score 0):

If you re-install the wallet app and re-enter the mnemonic seed, you should be okay, though your question is slightly ambiguous in wording.